# how to record and save video from ip camera using AForge?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aforge

i try to do a recording function where the source is from IP Camera in C# using AForge but i cant really understand the coding as i am a new learner.. The recorded video will then saved in my computer.  
 as i konw this function is to write/create a video and save it in my storage.

```
AVIWriter writer = new AVIWriter("DIB ");
// create new AVI file and open it
writer.Open(@"C:\test.avi", 768, 576);
// create frame image
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(768, 576);

for (int i = 0; i < 240; i++)
{
// update image
image.SetPixel(i, i, Color.Red);
// add the image as a new frame of video file
writer.AddFrame(image);
}
writer.Close();
```

but how to read the mjepg form source file(IP cam) and pass it to AVIWriter?
can someone give me guidance on how to achieve that

new learner, please guide me....

Comment: What kind of "IP Camera" is it? Is it something like a high-performance Point Grey research camera, or more like a webcam? In both cases, the camera manufacturer's website should have instructions on how to obtain images from the camera.

Comment: Also, avoid `SetPixel` - it's a very slow operation. If you want to manipulate individual pixels I recommend `LockBits`.

Comment: @Dai its an Apexis IP cam(CCTV), i know where i can obtain image streaming from camera. My question is how do i read the streaming image(MJPEG) using AForge in C# and write to an AVI file and save to my storage.

Answer (score 4):

You need to reference 
AForge.video
AForge.video.VFW

If your camera provides an MJPEGstream then 
( sorry it’s in VB )

```
Imports AForge.Video
Imports AForge.Video.VFW
'…
Dim VideoStream As MJPEGStream = New MJPEGStream("<your MJPEG URL>")
Dim VFWriter = New AVIWriter(("your compression codec 4CC ex:xvid>"))
VFWriter.FrameRate = <framerate>

AddHandler VideoStream.NewFrame, AddressOf NewStreamFrame '<Your Handler>

'…

Public Sub StartRecording()
VFWriter.Open("<destinationFile.avi>", <FrameSize.Width>, <FrameSize.Height>)
‘FrameSize.Width and height must correspond to what your camera is sending
       VideoStream.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub StopRecording()
        VFWriter.Close()
End Sub


Private Sub NewStreamFrame(sender As System.Object, e As NewFrameEventArgs)
        VFWriter.AddFrame(e.Frame)
End Sub
```

The code is not complete I removed error handling and other decorations.
This code will read and save video without displaying it
If you already have a VideoSourcePlayer, the player can also fire a NewFrame event with the image frame as argument. In this case you will not need to manually add handler.

Comment: I got it working but i have a problem with the frame rate. If i leave the frame rate to default value(25pfs) the recorded video is playing too fast(record the video for 1 minute long but it play 5seconds), so i need to set the frame rate to 4-5 to get the normal video. Assuming that you already done the recording from IP camera using AForge, how high is your recorded video's frame rate you can get? And how to get higher frame rate. The Ip camera can support up to 30fps. At least i want to record video with frame rate as close as possible as the actual camera can support.

Comment: My case is a bit particular, I record a 4 fps mjpeg stream and the resulting fps is correct but I saw a lot of threads on this subject in AForge forum.
In general you can also modify the frame rate camera side, which one are you talking about? Camera or AviWriter side?

Comment: The camera's frame rate set to 30fps. By default, the AVIWriter frame rate is 25fps(fps not set). Of course i can modify the camera frame rate to lower and i set it to higher frame rate which is 30fps. But the recording using AForge cannot match the camera's frame rate. If i try to set the AVIWriter frame rate to 30fps same as the camera frame rate, the recorded video playing to fast in short time, so i need to lower the AVIWriter frame rate to 4-5fps and only then the video play in normal speed in a correct length of time. But it is no longer same as the cam fps.